# What does it mean that an hypotesis is consistent?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I am studying **concept learning**, and I am focusing on the concept of **consistency** for an hypotesis.

Consider an Hypotesis $h$, I have understood that it is consistent with a training set $D$ **iff** $h(x)=c(x)$ where $c(x)$ is the concept and this has to be verified for every sample $x$ in $D$.

For example consider the following training set:

[image]

and the following hypotesis:

$h_1=<?,?,?,Strong,?,?>$

I have that this is **not consistent** with D because for the example $3$ in $D$ we have $h(x)!=c(x)$.

I **don't understand why this hypotesis is not consistent.**

Infact, consider the following hypotesis:

$h=<Sunny,Warm,?,Strong,?,?>$

this **is consistent** with $D$ because for each example in $D$ we have $h(x)=c(x)$.

But **why the first hypotesis $h_1$ is not consistent while the second,$h$, is consistent?**

Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: have that this is not consistent with D because for the example 3 in D we have h(x)!=c(x). This can not be interpreted. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not especially familiar with this but from the example provided we can deduce that:

- An hypothesis is a partial assignment of values to the features. That is, by "applying the hypothesis" we obtain a subset of instances for which the features satisfy the hypothesis.
- An hypothesis is consistent with the data if the target variable (called "concept" apparently, here `EnjoySport` in the example) has the same value for any instance in the subset obtained by applying it.

First case: $h_1=<?,?,?,Strong,?,?>$. All 4 instances in the data satisfy $h_1$, so the subset satisfying $h_1$ is the whole data. However the concept `EnjoySport` can have two values for this subset, so $h_1$ is not consistent.

Second case: $h_2=<Sunny,Warm,?,Strong,?,?>$. This hypothesis is more precise than $h_1$: the subset of instances which satisfy $h_2$ is $\{1,2,4\}$. The concept `EnjoySport` always have value `Yes` for every instance in this subset, so $h_2$ is consistent with the data.

Intuitively, the idea is that an hypothesis is consistent with the data if knowing the values specified by the hypothesis gives a 100% certainty about the value of the target variable.